# toDigits but padded with zeros Haskell

Tags: haskell, integer

I'm new to Haskell and have the following assignment:

> Convert positive Integers to a list of its digits, but if the list has negative number or is 0, return the empty list. If the list is shorter than 9 digits, it should be padded from the left with zeros.

I've managed to write codes for padding, and for `toDigits`, but I'm not sure how to combine them, please help. My code:

```
toDigits :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigits 0 = []
toDigits x = (if (x < 0) then [] else (toDigits (x `div` 10)) ++ [x `mod` 10]) 

padLeft :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]  
-- I thought about calling the  function with 9 and 0 and the list
padLeft n x xs = replicate (n - length xs) x ++ xs
```

Examples:

```
toDigits 496351 = [0,0,0,4,9,6,3,5,1]
toDigits 0 = []
toDigits (-17) = []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to augment your `padLeft` definition with one more clause, to intercept the `[]` case:

```
padLeft' :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]  
padLeft' _ _ [] = ........    -- complete the definition
padLeft' n x xs = replicate (n - length xs) x ++ xs
```

Now,

```
> padLeft' 9 0 $ toDigits (496351)
[0,0,0,4,9,6,3,5,1]

> padLeft' 9 0 $ toDigits (-17)
[]

> padLeft' 9 0 $ toDigits (0)
[]
```

You can package this up as one function call,

```
toDigitsPadded :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigitsPadded n = padLeft' 9 0 $ toDigits n
```

or, shorter,

```
toDigitsPadded :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigitsPadded  =  padLeft' 9 0 . toDigits
```

This is how we *compose* bigger programs from smaller functions, in Haskell. Non-coincidentally, the `.` operator is called the "function *composition* operator", it composes two functions right-to-left, as seen above, so that the output of the second function (on the right of the "dot") is used as an input to the first one (on the left):

```
(f  .  g) x  =  f (g x)
```

(*not* a pseudocode). This follows the usual function call syntax directionality, when explicit arguments are used.

There is also a left-to-right function composition operator,

```
(g >>> f) x  =  f (g x)
             =  g x & f
             =  x & g & f
```

which lets us focus, mentally, more on the *data* flowing through these functions in the left-to-right direction. Same with the operator `&` which is nothing more than just

```
x & g  =  g $ x 
       =  g  x
```

whichever is more conducive to our thought process at any given moment.

Comment: but I want to activate padLeft by calling toDigit, so that when calling to toDigit, the numbers will be padded already

Comment: @Yuki1112 I've edited. you can change the names of the functions as you see fit. :)

Comment: just to make sure that I got you right, I needed to add padLeft n x [] = []
for the empty case, correct?(: